# How to write a video file using Moviepy

Tags: python, audio, video

I am trying to implement a startle burst into a .mp4 file. I have been able to do this successfully but how I have altered the original audio results in an array. The trouble I am having is that the 'write_videofile' function seems to only take a specific type of structure in order to write the audio file. This is what I have so far any help would be great.

```
#Necessary imports 
import os as os 
import moviepy.editor as mp
from playsound import playsound
import librosa as librosa
import librosa.display
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
from moviepy.audio.AudioClip import AudioArrayClip

#Set working directory 
os.chdir('/Users/matthew/Desktop/Python_startle')

#Upload the video and indicate where in the clip the burst should be inserted 
vid = mp.VideoFileClip("37vids_balanced/Baby_Babble.mp4") 
audio, sr = librosa.load('37vids_balanced/Baby_Babble.mp4') 
librosa.display.waveplot(audio, sr = sr) 
sd.play(audio, sr) 

audio_duration = librosa.get_duration(filename = '37vids_balanced/Baby_Babble.mp4') 
start_point_sec = 6 
start_point_samp = start_point_sec * sr 
burst_samp = int(sr * .05) #how many samples are in the noise burst
burst_window = audio[start_point_samp : start_point_samp + burst_samp].astype(np.int32) #Isolating part of the audio clip to add burst to 

#Creating startle burst 
noise = np.random.normal(0,1,len(burst_window))

#Inserting the noise created into the portion of the audio that is wanted 
audio[start_point_samp : start_point_samp + burst_samp] = audio[start_point_samp : start_point_samp + burst_samp].astype(np.int64) + noise #Puts the modified segment into the original audio 
librosa.display.waveplot(audio, sr = sr) 
sd.play(audio, sr) 


new_vid = vid.set_audio(audio)
sd.play(new_vid.audio, sr) 

#Trying to get the  audio into the proper form to convert into a mp4 

new_vid.audio = [[i] for i in new_vid.audio] #This makes the data into a list because the 'AudioArrayClip' could not take in an array because an array is not 'iterable' this might not be the best solution but it has worked so far
new_vid.audio = AudioArrayClip(new_vid.audio, fps = new_vid.fps)

new_vid.write_videofile('37vids_balanced_noise/Baby_Babble.mp4')
```

Maybe there is an easier way to take the array into an iterable form that would work.

Comment: Just a tip: You might not want to comment every single line of code. Python emphasizes readability, so, most often, the statements themselves describe what the code does. Usually, if it really is necessary to comment every line of code to be understandable, you may be writing statements which are too complicated. Personally, I comment chunks of related code, just giving a summary of what those lines do.

Comment: @JacobLee I appreciate the advice do you have any comments that would address the question at hand?